# Sending Many Requests Hangs in Node

Tags: node.js, heroku, request

I'm connecting to the Riot API to obtain images from their data dragon services using the Request package. Once the Request gives me a response, I save the image onto the disk. Saving champion thumbnails is a cinch; no problems. However, item thumbnails have been failing 95% of the time. It only occasionally works on my local machine.

I've been deploying the app to Heroku and the images were all successfully loaded the 4/4 times I deployed. Unfortunately, as stated earlier, when I run the server locally, my internet actually hangs and I become unable to use the internet only when I try to obtain the item thumbnails.

Here is a snippet:

```
function retrieveAndProcessImage(imageURL, callback) {
    "use strict";

    console.log(imageURL);

    request(imageURL, {encoding: 'binary'}, function (req_err, req_res) {

        // Extract the image name by looking at the very end of the path.
        var pathArray = (imageURL).split('/');
        var imageName = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];

        if (req_err) {
            console.log("Couldn't retrieve " + imageName);
        } else {
            callback(imageName, req_res['body']);
        }
    });
};
```

The above snippet obtains the image from the API. When it occasionally works, the proper image is saved so I at least know that the URLs are all correct. The callback is just an fs.writeFile that writes the file locally so I don't have to send another request.

```
function retrieveAndProcessJson(dataURL, callback) {
    "use strict";

    request(dataURL, function (req_err, req_res) {
        // Try to parse the JSON.
        try {
            var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(req_res['body']);
        } catch (err) {
            _errorMessage(dataURL);
            return;
        }

        // If the parsing failed or the retrieval failed, connection failed.
        if (bodyJSON['status'] !== undefined) {
            _errorMessage(dataURL);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise output the success.
        console.log("Connected to " + dataURL);

        // Callback.
        callback(req_res['body']);
    });
};
```

The above obtains the raw JSON and passes the result of it to a callback.

```
fileFuncs.retrieveAndProcessJson(dataURL, function (raw_body) {
    var bodyJSON = JSON.parse(raw_body);
    _saveData(raw_body);
    _saveImages(bodyJSON['data'])
});
```

and save images is:

```
function _saveImages(dataJSON) {
    var filePath;
    var itemKey;
    var item;

    var imageURL;
    var imageName;

    // Check to see the destination folder exists, and create if it doesn't.
    fileFuncs.checkFolder(api_constants.itemThumbnailPath);

    // For each item in the item JSON, save the thumbnail.
    for (itemKey in dataJSON) {
        if (dataJSON.hasOwnProperty(itemKey)) {
            item = dataJSON[itemKey];

            // The image are saved as #{id}.png
            imageName = item['id'] + '.png';

            imageURL = api_constants.itemThumbnailURL + imageName;

            // Retrieve the file from the API.
            fileFuncs.retrieveAndProcessImage(imageURL, function (fileName, image) {
                filePath = api_constants.itemThumbnailPath + fileName;

                fs.writeFile(filePath, image, { encoding: 'binary' }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("\t" + fileName + " already exists.");
                        return;
                    }

                    console.log("\tThumbnail " + fileName + " was saved.");
                })
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'd rather not have to deploy to Heroku each and every time I want to see what the changes in my code look like. Are there any solutions where I could potentially put some time between each request? Alternatively, just something that would let me do mass amounts of requests without hanging my internet.

Comment: Where is the code that does the mass requests?

Comment: You can add a delay using `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: Updated the snippets.

I looked into setTimeout, but if at all possible, I'd prefer not to create a timeout since it works when I deploy the code and only fails when I locally test.